# MarkerCluster refresh after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, google-maps

I have an AJAX function that queries posts based on users by a certain role which is fine and works but the problem is that I am trying to refresh the markers on Google Maps after the AJAX is complete and the posts have been queried.

In my AJAX call I input the html output of the results into a div and I am trying to get the map to basically recognize and identify the results in that div and update the markers based on the results in that div.

So for example, when the page loads, there are initially 18 results on the map and when the AJAX call is complete, there is meant to be 3 results but when I reinitialize the map after the AJAX call, the original 18 results still appear on the map.

I think the problem might be either in the $each function or in the map function as it's not updating the markers correctly. When I logged the titles of the results within the each function, all 18 original results were being returned, even after the AJAX call is complete and there are 3 results that have been outputted by HTML in to the results div.

I hope I have explained my issue clear enough and hopefully someone out there might be able to help me. I'll paste all the relevant code below.

**AJAX function to fetch results:**

```
$('#private').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var owner = $(this).data('owner');
  var res = $('.total-matches').data('res');

  $('#stm_owner').val(owner);
  $('#stm_res').val(res);
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var data_form = $('.filters').closest('form').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    context: this,
    data: data_form + '&action=ajax_filter',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.ajax-row').addClass('loading');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.sorting').html(data.html);
      $('.map-results').html(data.html);
      $('.total-matches span').text(' ' + data.total);
      $('.ajax-row').removeClass('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('.timeago').timeago();
      initGoogleMap(markersInfo);
    }
  });
});
```

**Google Maps function:**

```
var markersInfo = $('.ia-map').map(function() {
  var info = {
    id: $(this).data('map-id'),
    address: $(this).data('map-address'),
    title: $(this).data('map-title'),
    price: $(this).data('map-price'),
    latitude: $(this).data('map-latitude'),
    longitude: $(this).data('map-longitude'),
    html: "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">",
    link: $(this).data("map-link"),
    contentHtml: "<div class='image'>" + "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">" + "</div>" + '<b>' + $(this).data('map-title') + '</b><br>' + "<div class='changeprice'><div style='display: none;' class='currency-selector'></div>" + $(this).data('map-price') + "</div>" + "<br><a href='" + $(this).data("map-link") + "'>More>></a>"
  };
  return info;
}).get();

var distinctMarkerInfo = [];
markersInfo.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!distinctMarkerInfo.some(function(distinct) {
      return distinct.id == item.id;
    })) distinctMarkerInfo.push(item);
});

initGoogleMap(distinctMarkerInfo);

// GMAP ON SEARCH RESULTS PAGE
function initGoogleMap(markersInfo) {
  var mapOptions = {
      // zoom: 2,
      // center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.334430, -7.736673)
    },
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
    mapElement = document.getElementById('map_results'),
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
  var markerList = []; // create an array to hold the markers
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var iconBase = '../assets/images/';

  $.each(markersInfo, function(key, val) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      //map: map,
      position: {
        lat: parseFloat(val.latitude),
        lng: parseFloat(val.longitude)
      },
      title: val.title,
      icon: iconBase + 'single.png',
      info: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: val.contentHtml
      })
    });

    markerList.push(marker); // add the marker to the list

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      marker.info.open(map, marker);
    });

    var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
    bounds.extend(loc);
  });

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.panToBounds(bounds);

  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerList, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
}
```

**And finally the map html:**

```
<div id="map_results" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
```

**and the div that is outputted in to the results div for each result after the AJAX call**

```
<div class="ia-map" data-price="<?php echo esc_attr($data_price) ?>" data-date="<?php echo get_the_date('Ymdhi') ?>" data-mileage="<?php echo esc_attr($data_mileage); ?>" data-map-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-map-address="<?php echo $location; ?>" data-map-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-map-price="<?php echo esc_attr($price); ?>" data-map-latitude="<?php echo $lat; ?>" data-map-longitude="<?php echo $lng; ?>" data-map-image="<?php echo esc_url($img[0]); ?>" data-map-link="<?php the_permalink() ?>" <?php if(isset($distance)): ?>data-distance="<?php echo esc_attr(floatval($distance)); ?>"<?php endif; ?>></div>
```

**and finally the results div itself**

```
<div class="map-results" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see how you are getting value for markerInfo variable in your ajax complete event.

Comment: @FahamShaikh the only reason I call `initGoogleMap(markersInfo)` on complete is because I thought I had to reinitialize the map in order to refresh the markers. I wasn't really sure what I was doing there to be honest lol

Comment: You are right in calling the function but wrong in passing the variable. If you receive the marker data on ajax completion then you should compile it in format you require and pass to initialization function.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Right, I don't necessarily get the marker data on success but I kind of do in a sense that the results div is updated after the ajax call and only relevant results will be displayed _(divs with the `ia-map` class)_ but other than that I don't know how to pass the data back through the markercluster. If you could edit my above code and show me what you're talking about I would greatly appreciate it thanks :)

Comment: Check my reply. If you populate the data in any input after the ajax has completed then you can use the code inside my onChange function and get the work done. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer based on your ajax call (You only need to change this in your code).

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    context: this,
    data: data_form + '&action=ajax_filter',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.ajax-row').addClass('loading');
    },
    success: function (response) {
       //This logs the ajax response.
       console.log(response);
       $('.sorting').html(response.html);
       $('.map-results').html(response.html);
       $('.total-matches span').text(' ' + response.total);
       $('.ajax-row').removeClass('loading');
       var ajaxMarkersInfo = [];
       $('.map-results .ia-map').each(function(index, el){
           //var ajaxMarker = [];
           var mapID = $(this).attr('data-map-id');
           var mapAddress = $(this).attr('data-map-address');
           var mapTitle = $(this).attr('data-map-title');
           var mapPrice = $(this).attr('data-map-price');
           var mapLatitude = $(this).attr('data-map-latitude');
           var mapLongitude = $(this).attr('data-map-longitude');
           var mapHTML = "<img src=" + $(this).attr('data-map-image') + ">";
           var mapLink = $(this).attr('data-map-link');
           var mapContentHTML = "<div class='image'>" + "<img src=" + $(this).attr('data-map-image') + ">" + "</div>" + '<b>' + $(this).attr('data-map-title') + '</b><br>' + "<div class='changeprice'><div style='display: none;' class='currency-selector'></div>" + $(this).attr('data-map-price') + "</div>" + "<br><a href='" + $(this).attr("data-map-link") + "'>More>></a>";
           var ajaxMarker = {
               id: mapID,
               address: mapAddress,
               title: mapTitle,
               price: mapPrice,
               latitude: mapLatitude,
               longitude: mapLongitude,
               html: mapHTML,
               link: mapLink,
               contentHtml: mapContentHTML
           };
           ajaxMarkersInfo.push(ajaxMarker);
       });
       console.log(ajaxMarkersInfo);
       initGoogleMap(ajaxMarkersInfo);
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('.timeago').timeago();

    }
});
```

This should work for you but for verification I have logged the `ajaxMarkersInfo` variable in the console so you can log the `info` variable from your code and compare.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting errors in the ajaxMarker.push and I'm not sure how to fix it..

Comment: The errors occur with `id:` `address:` etc... when I get rid of those there are no more errors. for example `ajaxMarker.push(mapID);`

Comment: Sorry I am a bit sleepy right now(its 3:17 in the night). I noticed the mistake previously and instead of fixing it fully, I did it part way only. It should work now.

Comment: Sorry for keeping you up so late. I am no longer getting errors but the console is now logging an empty array whereas before it was working when I had it the way I explained it using just `mapID`...

Comment: Please share the output of the logged data. I have logged response of ajax request first and that will be useful to identify your issue.

Comment: I don't understand what happened though, I was initially getting an array after I resolved the initial errors but now even when I return to what you initially posted I'm still getting an empty array so I don't know what is going on...

Comment: I was able to get it working in the end thank you. I just resolved a few errors myself but it works now.

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to what you are attempting so I you can look at my code, modify it and use it for your purpose.

```
var map;
var elevator;
var markers = [];
function mapinitialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.603296, 81.885962),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        styles: [
            {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#ff8040"
                },
                {
                    "weight": 1.5
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "labels",
                "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('hp-map-js'), myOptions);
}
function mapMark(receivedAddress = '') {
    //Loop through all the markers and remove
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    var icon = '/wp-content/themes/sssbv/assets/img/homepage/map/logo-map.png';
    var addresses = receivedAddress != '' ? receivedAddress : ['Norway', 'Africa', 'Asia','North America','South America'];
    console.log(addresses);
    for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
        //I am geocoding the coordinates from individual location address.
        jQuery.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            map.setCenter(data.results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(6);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: icon
                }));
            }, (x+1*200));
        });
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var loaded = false;
    //This is the part you have to change.
    //Instead of on change you will use your ajax output on completion.
    $(".location-selector").on('change', '#district-js', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Here I am getting the state and district name.
        var selectedDistrictVal = $(this).val();
        selectedDistrictVal = selectedDistrictVal.replace('-', ' ');
        var selectedStateVal = $('.location-selector #state-js').val();
        selectedStateVal = selectedStateVal.replace('-', ' ');
        if (selectedDistrictVal != '') {
            var createdAddress = [];
            createdAddress.push(selectedDistrictVal);
            mapMark(createdAddress);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but I am a newbie when it comes to this so I am not exactly sure as to how I need to change and update my code with your code, can you help me out with that please?

Comment: @MattH That is a bit difficult without understanding the output of your ajax request. Can you help me by providing that output data .

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @MattH If you are using my sample code you simply need to pass the address in json object format. If you are using your own code then I may have to paste another solution.

Comment: So on success do you get multiple div with `ia-map` class?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's why I was thinking is there no way to somehow grab all divs that have a certain class and use their data attributes to populate the markercluster the same way it does it on page load. I mean if it's possible to achieve this on page load then I don't understand why it can't be done through ajax..

Comment: I am adding another answer based on your ajax and ia-map class